# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading) in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am getting this call from the famous ApiPokemon:
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151

Once I have that data I want to pass it through another method (**_getPokemonData**) to map the complete data for each Pokémon.

However when I create this VueJS method I get this error:

***Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_getPokemonData')***

**Why can't I call the _getPokemonData method inside the forEach?**
This is my code:

```
mounted() {
    this.$http
      .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151")
      .then((response) => {
        //this.pokemons = response.data.results;
        this.pokemons = response.data.results.forEach(function(pokemon){
          this._getPokemonData(pokemon); 
        });
      });

    this.$http
      .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/")
      .then((response) => {
        this.types = response.data.results;
      });
  },

  methods: {
    _getPokemonData(pokemon) {
      console.log(pokemon);
    },
```

Comment: well, maybe this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch the function in forEach for a arrow function. by using 'function' you create a new scope which hijacks the 'this' reference.

see [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-zhukovsky-go1nux?file=/src/App.vue)